# Receive JSON object in index php, process JSON info on page and send back JSON response. How to go about it?

Tags: php, json, request, response

I am in a situation where a website will redirect the user back to our site (on index.php) and send a JSON request. I will parse the JSON request and process it accordingly and then post back a JSON response.

I am using this code to take the JSON input request in my index.php:

```
$data_back = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
//process $data_back
// create json response
$response = array("RESPONSE_CODE"=>"0","RESPONSE_DESCRIPTION"=>"OK","PAYMENT_ID"=>"XYZ");
// set header as json
header("Content-type: application/json");
// send response
echo json_encode($response);
```

However, by using the echo, the content gets displayed on the main page (index.php). If I don't use echo then the response is not sent back to the other site that sent the request and neither am I able to receive the data in the input stream.

I am trying to simulate the other site with the following code:

```
//set POST variables address and json string
    $url = 'http://XYZ.com/MYSITE/index.php';
    $fields = array("CARD_NUMBER"=>"123","CUSTOMER_NAME"=>"ABC","RECEIVED_AMOUNT"=>"5000","REQUEST_TYPE"=>"PAYMENT_RECEIVED");

    //url-ify the data for the JSON POST
    $fields_string = json_encode($fields);

    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1);

    //execute post
    $jsonResult = curl_exec($ch);

    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);

    $results = json_decode($jsonResult, true);
```

I don't know how to approach this. Please guide me on can I process the JSON on my index.php and send back the response as well. I am new to JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Just Tested your script and it works fine ... they are 2 possible reasons

A. Invalid `URL`

B. Failed Curl Request

Put the on top of your script

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
```

and also use this to caputure curl error

```
if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
```

Comment: On further consultation, I found that what I was looking for is not possible. Thanks for taking out the time to answer.